# Update all documents setting a value equal to value of an array where index taken from another value (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell

I am trying to execute a mongo Shell command on a 80k documents Collection in MongoDB.

Here is a sample doc:

```
{ 
   "weights":[ 
      { 
         "amount":100,
         "description":"grams",
         "grams":100
      },
      { 
         "amount":1,
         "description":"cup",
         "grams":258
      },
      { 
         "amount":1,
         "description":"tbsp",
         "grams":16
      },
      { 
         "amount":1,
         "description":"tsp",
         "grams":5.38
      }
   ],
   "default_units":2,
   "nutrition":{ 
      "calories":598,
      "carbs":22.31,
      "fats":51.36,
      "proteins":22.21,
   },
   "serving_calories":95,
   "serving_carbs":3,
   "serving_fats":8,
   "serving_proteins":2,
}
```

**What I want to do is go over each Doc in the collection and update the "serving_calories" field to be as follows:**

```
serving_calories = doc.nutrition.calories * (doc.weights[doc.default_units].grams / 100);
```

So executing this properly would make **serving_calories = 598 * (16 / 100) = ‭95.68‬**

I wasn't able to find the right commands to be able to do the array index as needed from another value. What is the right mongo command to execute?

Answer (score 0):

I figured I was not selecting the correct database before executing the script. Here is my script anyways:

```
db.foods.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  db.foods.updateOne({ _id: doc._id },{ $set: { 
    serving_calories: doc.nutrition.calories *  (doc.weights[doc.default_units].grams / 100)
  } } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in an atomic update operation with MongoDB 4.2 and newer. The new versions have the update method which now takes a document or an [aggregate pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline) where the following stages can be used:

- [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields) and its alias [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set)
- [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) and its alias
- [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/#pipe._S_unset) [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/#pipe._S_replaceRoot) and its alias [`$replaceWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/#pipe._S_replaceWith).

Armed with the above, your [update operation with the aggregate pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#example-2) will have three steps i.e.

1. Get the document in the `weights` array that corresponds to the index depicted by 
   the `default_units` field and set it to a new field `serving_weight` to be used 
   in the next pipeline.
2. Set the `serving_calories` field with the result of the above computation.
3. Remove the new field from stage 1 `serving_weight`

Your update operation follows:

```
db.foods.update(
    { },
    [
        { "$set": {
            "serving_weight": {
                "$arrayElemAt": ["$weights", "$default_units"]
            }
        } },
        { "$set": {
            "serving_calories": {
                "$multiply": [
                    "$nutrition.calories",
                    { "$divide": [ "$serving_weight.grams", 100 ] }
                ]
            }
        } },
        { "$unset": [ "serving_weight" ] }
    ]
);
```

You would of course need to add in logic for validation that is where elements don't exist, you would need to use [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) and substitute the appropriate values or default values.